# Is 'xpack' required to be purchased for HTTPS output to Elasticsearch from Logstash?

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, https, logstash, xpack

I am using Logstash 5.6.5. So far used elasticsearch (version 5.6.5) output with HTTP protocol and no authentication. Now Elasticsearch is being secured using basic authentication (user/password) and CA certified HTTPS URL. I don't have any control over the elasticsearch server. I just use it to output to from Logstash.

So far I don't have any xpack installed. Is 'xpack' required to be purchased for HTTPS output and basic authentication to Elasticsearch from Logstash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that **NO need for 'xpack' installation** to connect to a HTTPS URL of elasticsearch and for the basic authentication. Below answer refers to the configuration I used which was working as per my requirement.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49126629/1651350